# Multiple solutions to a first-order differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I'm supposed to find the solution of $$(xy-1)\frac{dy}{dx}+y^2=0$$
The solution in the book manipulates it to $$\frac{dx}{dy}+\frac{x}{y}=\frac{1}{y^2}$$ and proceeds to use an integrating factor to solve it to $$xy=\ln{y}+c$$
Which makes sense, but I did it by isolating the differential of y, substituting $xy=v$, and simplifying it to $$\frac{1-v}{v}dv=\frac{dx}{x}$$ which gives, on solving, $$\ln{y}+c=\ln{x^2}+\frac{y}{x}$$ Which isn't the same.

I can't see any flaw in what I did except for dividing variables throughout the equation (which I see everywhere in methods of solving differential equations, without a clue as to why.)

Can anyone help me with where I got it wrong?

**EDIT:** I'll add some detail on my steps; $$xy=c\\ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y^2}{xy-1}\\ x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{v^2}{1-v}+v=\frac{v}{1-v}\\ \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{(1-v)dv}{v}$$

Comment: I guess that you made a sign error in $\dfrac{1-v}vdv=\dfrac{dx}x$.

Comment: "but I did it by isolating the differential of y, substituting =, and simplifying it to..."  Can you expand these steps?  I think this is where your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $$\frac{1-v}{v} dv =\frac{dx}{x} $$, you should get $$\ln v -v +C =\ln x  \\ \ln(xy) -xy +C =\ln x \\ \ln x +\ln y -xy +C =\ln x \\ xy =\ln y +C$$

You probably mistook $v$ for $\frac yx$.

Comment: The silliest mistake....Thanks.